# Undocummented operator in ANTLR4 grammar: expr op=('*'|'/') expr

Tags: antlr4, context-free-grammar

The book of anltr4 includes this example, in lableledExpr.g4
https://github.com/jszheng/py3antlr4book/blob/master/04-Calc/LabeledExpr.g4

with these lines:

```
expr:   expr op=('*'|'/') expr      # MulDiv
    |   expr op=('+'|'-') expr      # AddSub
... ;
```

but I can't find the documentation which is the objetive, and meaning of `op=('*'|'/')`

would that be equivalent to?

```
expr:   expr opmult expr      # MulDiv
    |   expr opplus expr      # AddSub
... ;

opmult : ('*'|'/') ;
opplus : ('+'|'-') ;
```

Comment: FYI, they're called "Rule Element Labels": https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#rule-element-labels . And the labels are used in the visitor https://github.com/jszheng/py3antlr4book/blob/master/04-Calc/MyVisitor.py (search for "ctx.op")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s “similar”, but not the same.

The `op=('*'|'/')` just means that, if the `’*’` or `’/‘` tokens are encountered they will be available through an `op` property.  This can be used for any part of a parser rule and just allows you to name parts of your rule so that you context object will be easier to work with in your code.

The

```
expr:   expr opmult expr      # MulDiv
    |   expr opplus expr      # AddSub
... ;

opmult : ('*'|'/') ;
opplus : ('+'|'-') ;
```

Will parse the same input, but will put the `’*’` or `’/‘` token into a separate context object.

Look at your generated code each way and the difference will be obvious.  (Maybe even try the first rule as just `expr ('*'|'/') expr`.  And think about the code you’d need to determine which operator was used, compared to the code when you have the `op=`.)